# Inline VB for Parsing XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, inline

I have an XML feed that I get returned as a response to a web service call:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <CustomerGetResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://WHATEVER/webservice">
    <UserExists>false</UserExists>
    <DisableAccountFlag>false</DisableAccountFlag>
</CustomerGetResult>
```

I take that response and store it as a string named: strRead. I then attempted to get the values using the following (without success):

```
Dim XMLString = XDocument.Parse(strRead)
Response.Write("UserExists: " & XMLString.<CustomerGetResult>.<UserExists>.Value)
Response.Write("DisableAccountFlag: " & XMLString.<CustomerGetResult>.<DisableAccountFlag>.Value)
```

I have also tried other ways without success:

```
Dim doc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXML(strRead)
dim SymbolText as String = doc.SelectSingleNode("//CustomerGetResult/UserExists").Value
Response.Write(SymbolText)
```

Can anyone help me at this point? This is inline inside an aspx file.

Comment: You need to use the namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two choices

```
        Dim strRead = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" & _
            "<CustomerGetResult xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns=""http://WHATEVER/webservice"">" & _
            "<UserExists>false</UserExists>" & _
            "<DisableAccountFlag>false</DisableAccountFlag>" & _
        "</CustomerGetResult>"

        Dim XMLString As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(strRead)
        Dim root As XElement = XMLString.Root
        Dim ns As XNamespace = root.GetDefaultNamespace()

        'Method 1
        Console.WriteLine("UserExists: {0}", CType(XMLString.Descendants(ns + "UserExists").FirstOrDefault(), String))
        Console.WriteLine("DisableAccountFlag: {0}", CType(XMLString.Descendants(ns + "DisableAccountFlag").FirstOrDefault(), String))

        'Method 2
        Console.WriteLine("UserExists: {0}", CType(XMLString.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "UserExists").FirstOrDefault(), String))
        Console.WriteLine("DisableAccountFlag: {0}", CType(XMLString.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "DisableAccountFlag").FirstOrDefault(), String))
```

Answer (score 0):

Namespace is the key:

```
Dim myNamespace As XNamespace = YourXMLNameSpace

For Each report As XElement In xmlr.Descendants(myNamespace + "CustomerGetResult")
  Console.WriteLine(report.Element(myNamespace + "UserExists").Value)
Next
```